# How to debug Cucumber in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, cucumberjs, javascript-debugger

I was trying to debug Cucumber scenarios in Visual Studio code and made below changes in the `launch.json`.

```
{
            "name": "e2e",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\.bin\\cucumber-js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": ["--no-timeouts", "--colors"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\features\\step_definitions\\*.js"
            ]
},
```

However, I am not able run a debug session using the above configuration. The step def. files I created in JavaScript. 
So, just need a help on the script above if that looks fine?

Comment: What breakpoint? Where?

Comment: Breakpoint somewhere in the code! The question above is to validate my config. script in `launch.json` for cucumber. Hope it is clear to you now..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try below configuration to make your debug working in VS Code. In the `outFiles` give your feature file path.

```
{
    "name": "e2e",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js",
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/features/*.feature"
    ]
}
```

**============================================**
**UPDATE AS OF cucumber ^5.0.2:**

```
{
    "name": "NPM Cukes",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
    "args": [
        "path/to/features/**/*.feature",
        "-r",
        "path/to/steps/**/*",
        "--tags",
        "@your-tags"
    ]
}
```

If you want to debug only CURRENT feature, add this to launch.json

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js",
    "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
    "name": "Cukes current",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber"
    }
}
```

Comment: the program has now moved (my version is 7.3.2) to `@cucumber/cucumber`.

Answer (score 5):

Tweaking the answer from Mukesh Rawat plus ensuring additional file paths were correct, got it working for me, :

Launch.json

```
{
    "name": "DebugMode",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
    "args": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/features/*.feature",
        "--tags", "@debug"
    ]
}
```

Workspace.json

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "features/steps/*.js"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*.feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "settings": {},
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "/Users/{me}/Documents/{project folder}/{project name}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect=1337 --debug-brk --nolazy node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js --tags @debug --format json:./reports/report.json",
```

CucumberTest.feature

```
@debug
Scenario: Validate I can get debug working
```

Comment: do we need to keep these 2 files under .vscode folder?

Answer (score 3):

When working with Ruby, it could be used on [this way](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/5.-Example-configurations#cucumber) to run specific feature files:

```
{
    "name": "Cucumber",
    "type": "Ruby",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/cucumber",
    "args": [
        "--tags", "@Mytags",
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with the latest Cucumber, Playwright, typescript as of January 2023 - F5 (run in VSCode) - set `debugger` in ts step files and use `.vscode/launch.json` (you might tweak your reports location)

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "debugMode",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",      
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen", 
      "program": "node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
      "args": [
        "./features/*.feature",
        "--require-module",
        "ts-node/register",
        "--require", 
        "./steps/*.steps.ts",        
        "--tags",
        "@demoX",       
        "--format", "progress",
        "--format", "json:./Reports/cucumber_report.json"    
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
{
    "name": "DebugMode",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
    "args": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/features/*.feature",
        "--tags", "@debug"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way I've found to run Cucumber.js in the VS Code debugger:

1. Set JavaScript debugger auto attach to "onlyWithFlag" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type "Toggle Auto Attach")
2. Run Cucumber.js as follows: `node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js <args...>`
3. For convenience, [set an NPM run script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script) in your test project for "debug" so you can run this as `npm run debug -- <args...>`