# How do you debug the cucumber step definitions w/ Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, protractor, visual-studio-code, bdd, cucumberjs

I'm using the protractor-cucumber-framework to create a testbed environment for our QA team. I've searched around and been able to find zero help in implementing VS Code's debugging capability for use in this code. Has anyone does this? I'd really like to step away from `console.log()` statements.

Comment: for playwright with cucumber with typescript steps - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834293/how-to-debug-cucumber-in-visual-studio-code-vscode/75214824#75214824

Answer (score 2):

1) Upgrade your Nodejs to 8 and later 
2) Create a folder `.vscode` under your project base directory 
3) Create a file `launch.json` under `.vscode` 
4) Copy below content into `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "gie",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "args": [
            "config/gie.config.js",
            "--browser=chrome"
        ]
    }]
}
```

The `${workspaceFolder}` represent your project base directory 
The first value in `args` is your protractor config file, you can use relative path to `${workspaceFolder}` 
The second and next value in `args` is command options as you type in command line to run test.

My Environment:  VSCode 1.8.1,  Nodejs v8.9.0, Protractor 5.2.0,

Comment: it works for me when I have put the file name directly in args file config,js instead of command file "protractor conf.js"