# How to debug Cucumber - Protractor in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, protractor, cucumber, angular-e2e

I am trying to debug Gherkin Cucumber scenarios in Visual Studio Code but I am getting the following error:-

**Parse error in 'zFunctionalTests\protractor_ui.conf.js': (1:1): expected: #EOF, #Language, #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'var baseConfig = require('./protractor_base.conf.js');'**

I have created the following configuration:

**launch.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\cucumber\\bin\\cucumber-js",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\zFunctionalTests\\protractor_ui.conf.js",
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/FunctionalTests/features/*.feature"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**protractor_ui.conf.js**

```
var baseConfig = require('./protractor_base.conf.js');
var localConfig = baseConfig.config;

localConfig.capabilities = {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
            '--start-maximized',
            '--no-sandbox',
        ]
    }
}

exports.config = localConfig;
```

**protractor_base.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 15000,
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000/",
  specs: ["./features/*.feature"],
  framework: "custom",
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ["./steps/*.ts"],
    strict: true,
    dryRun: false,
    tags: true,
    profile: false,
    "no-source": true,
    tags: ["~@ignore"],
    compiler: []
  },
  capabilities: {},
  maxSessions: 1,
  multiCapabilities: {},
  allScriptsTimeout: 15000,
  getPageTimeout: 15000,
  onPrepare() {
    require("ts-node").register({
      project: "zFunctionalTests/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    });
    require("dotenv").config();
  }
};
```

I have tried things described in the following post but it's not working.

[How to debug Cucumber in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834293/how-to-debug-cucumber-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

It may be due to while execution its not picking up tsconfig in which the target es5 is mentioned.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create launch.json using node.js environment
2. Copy paste the below code

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "ng e2e",
"type": "node",
"request": "launch",
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
"protocol": "inspector",
"args": ["${workspaceFolder}/zFunctionalTests/protractor_single.conf.js"]
}]}
```

3. Now, go to step file and add breakpoints that you want to debug. And click on debug icon from vs code menu and start debugging

Note : workspace folder is your .vscode folder 
Hence, the paths mentioned here are based on assumptions of your folder structure. It may differ from actual path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you replaced types with:

```
"types": ["chai", "cucumber", "node"]
```

in tsconfig.json file?