# chrome debugs cucumber-js instead of features

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, cucumber

I have to be able to debug cucumber features. I used the solution from here
[How to debug Cucumber in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834293/how-to-debug-cucumber-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

I have launch.json in Visual Studio Code

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Via NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "windows": {
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd"
        },
        "env":{
           "NODE_PATH": "/usr/local/bin/"
        },
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run",
            "debug"
        ],
        "port": 5858
    }
```

I have a script in package.json

```
"debug": "node --inspect-brk=5858 ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js -r @babel/register -r @babel/polyfill -t '@ui'"
```

and when I run debug from VS code, and connect to the debugger from Chrome.
Chrome debugs cucumber-js instead of my features:

[image]

I don't want to debug cucumber scripts, I want debug my features.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug next, you will debug your code